# Referring to templated function in template

Tags: c++, c++11, template-templates

I would like to be able to name to a templated function in a template.

Since one can name a templated class using the "template template" syntax, and since one can name a function using the "function pointer" syntax, I was wondering whether there is a syntax (or a proposal) to name a function in a template without specifying to templates.

```
template<typename t_type>
struct A {
  t_type value;
};

template<template<typename> class t_type>
struct B {
  t_type<int> value;
};

template<int added>
constexpr int C (int value) {
  return value + added;
}

template<int (*function)(int)>
constexpr int D (int value) {
  return function(value);
}

// GOAL: Template argument referring to templated function
/*template<template<int> int (*function)(int)>
constexpr int E (int value) {
  return function<1>(value);
}*/

int main() {
  B<A> tt_good;
  int fp_good = D< &C<1> >(0);
  /*int fp_fail = E< &C >(0);*/

  return 0;
}
```

One possible work-around for anyone interested in this functionality to first wrap the function D in a struct with a call method named (for example) "method", pass the struct into E as a "template template" parameter, and then call "method" in E.

The reason that I don't like this approach is that it requires a wrapper structure for every variadic function that might be used in this way.

Comment: A template template parameter can only by a type template, if memory serves.

Comment: Your hypothetical call to `E` is missing a second template argument: if it were possible, it would be `E<C, 1>(0)`. At which point, you can just as well do `D<C<1>>(0)` to the same effect.

Comment: `My goal is to be able to expand a variadic into the template of a function, using a type that records the variadic.` I for one don't understand what this means. Perhaps you should show some code that explains what you are really trying to achieve, rather than the unworkable approach you hope might help get you there. See also: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik to avoid any confusion I've deleted the "goal" statement. And, as per your previous comment revised the code so that it shows  It is true that if I were to fully specify the template parameters then I would be able to refer to the function...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Just as there are cases where it is useful to refer to a template container type using a “template template” there are cases where I it would be helpful to refer to a templated function without having to specify the template parameters. So, I take it that the answer to my question is "there is no such syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass function templates as template parameters. The closest you can get is by using generic functors:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
void call(F f)
{
    f("hello, world\n");
}

int main()
{
    call([](auto value) { std::cout << value; });
}
```

If you don't have C++14 generic lambdas, you can write your own functors by hand:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
void call(F f)
{
    f("hello, world\n");
}

struct print
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T value) const
    {
        std::cout << value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    call(print());
}
```